How do I plot a R Studio 3 Variable Dataframe into a Heatmap?
I am currently doing a project in R, and have this dataframe:
lrdf
    nseg  meanlen        loglr
1     27 16.64982  2.163818549
2     18 15.49226  0.524823313
3     22 23.85373  0.570587756

I want to create a heatmap (or 2d density plot) in R Studio. I want nseg on the x-axis, meanlen on the y-axis,and loglr to be the z value which fills the heatmap.
I read that first the dataframe has to be converted from wide to long format. So i did this:
#Load dplyr package for data manipulation
library(dplyr)

#Load tidyr package (pivot_longer is from tidyr)
library(tidyr)

#Convert lrdf to a longer format
lrdf_long <- lrdf %>%
  #Pivot the specified column (loglr) to a long format
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(loglr),           # Column(s) to pivot (in this case, only loglr)
    names_to = "variable",      # Name of the new column for the original column names
    values_to = "loglr"         # Name of the new column for the values from loglr
  )

Which gave me this:
lrdf_long
# A tibble: 10,000 × 4
    nseg meanlen variable loglr
   <int>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1    27    16.6 loglr     2.16
 2    18    15.5 loglr     0.52
 3    22    23.9 loglr     0.57

Now, using ggplot to create the heatmap,i did this:
# Load ggplot2 package for data visualization
library(ggplot2)

# Load viridis package for color scales
library(viridis)

# Create a heatmap using ggplot2
ggplot(lrdf_long, aes(x = nseg, y = meanlen, fill = loglr)) +
  # Add a tile layer to create a heatmap based on loglr values
  geom_tile() + 
  
  # Use color scale from the viridis package
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  
  # Add plot labels
  labs(
    title = "Heatmap of loglr", # Title of the plot
    x = "nseg",                 # Label for the x-axis
    y = "meanlen"               # Label for the y-axis
  ) +
 

This code, though,gave me an empty plot. Have I wrongly converted the dataframe?
Is there anyone who could help solve this problem?

With your example data, the pivoting step is unnecessary (unless your original data are more complex). It does not provide any relevant change to the data. You may pass original lrdf. Also, your ggplot2 code is incomplete, the obsolete + at the end requires more arguments passed to ggplot (e.g. theme). Delete + at the end and rerun. However, this visualisation does not look very informative for the data provided as reprex.

ggplot(lrdf, aes(x = nseg, y = meanlen, fill = loglr)) +
geom_tile() +
Use color scale from the viridis package
scale_fill_viridis_c() +
Add plot labels
labs(
title = "Heatmap of loglr", # Title of the plot
x = "nseg",                 # Label for the x-axis
y = "meanlen"               # Label for the y-axis
)
I tried using this code and it gives me an empty plot. The lrdf dataframe contains 10000 values for each variable. You mentioned that this visualisation is not informative, do you have any suggestions of other visualisations?

For heatmap, you'd better use categorical (or at least integer) variables for x and y. Your y is double, and it can cause the rows too small to be visible. Cannot say more without some test data.

I'd recommend you to try CompleteHeatmap package to generate great heatmaps. Or its ggplot version eheat.

This would work:
library(ggplot2)

lrdf <- tibble::tribble(
  ~nseg, ~meanlen, ~loglr,
  27, 16.64982,  2.163818549,
  18, 15.49226,  0.524823313,
  22, 23.85373,  0.570587756
)

ggplot(lrdf, aes(x = nseg, y = meanlen, fill = loglr)) +
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_viridis_c()

